# how to track post request from node, if the data is received by requester or not

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, mongodb

I`m new at node

I use node as a back end server with mongodb
and call it using a android device

my case is I set timeout from android to post a request in node, then from android it just return timeout because it wait too long.. but after several seconds the data is created at mongodb because if internet is so slow so it takes several seconds, I just cut the connection in android and cant cut it at node.

anyone can help what is the best practice to using timeout in android? let say I set timeout to 60sec, if the request longer than 10 sec I want to cut the connection because it takes too long

thanks anyway :))

Comment: you have to set response after the request.

Comment: Show your tried code for batter solution

Comment: @KaushikMakwana

`exports.testInsert = function(req, res) {
    testModel.update({user_id: req.body.user_id}, {$set: {username: 'test'}}, {upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}).lean().exec(function(err, data) {
        if (err)
        {
            return res.send({
                err_num: 100000,
                err_str: err
            });
        }

        return res.send({
            err_num: 0,
            err_str: 'Success'
        })
    })
}`

i need to know how the response is going, the response received by android or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
exports.testInsert = function(req, res){
    testModel.update({user_id: req.body.user_id}, {$set: {username: 'test'}},{upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true})
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, data){ 
        if (err) { 
            res.send({ err_num: 100000, err_str: err });
            return false 
        }
        res.send({ err_num: 0, err_str: 'Success' }) 
    })
}
```

Comment: hmm the case is, I go through success response but the receiver (android) already cut the response.. and what I ask is how to know whenever the response is received by android or not?
TLDR: the node response always success but android already cut the connection, so I need to rollback the transaction